# Access the child component prop inside the parent component

Tags: styled-components

I'm facing a problem there is a styled component named `Breadcrumb` but that component depends upon 1 separate styled-components i.e `BreadcrumbItem`. Both components have different props.

**BreadcrumbItem.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const propTypes = {
  /** Active the current BreadcrumbItem. */
  active: PropTypes.bool,
  /** Additional classes. */
  className: PropTypes.string
};



const AbstractBreadcrumbItem = (props) => {
  const { className, active, ...attributes } = props;

  return <li {...attributes} className={className} />;
};

AbstractBreadcrumbItem.propTypes = propTypes;

const BreadcrumbItem = styled(AbstractBreadcrumbItem)``;

BreadcrumbItem.propTypes = propTypes;

export default BreadcrumbItem;
```

**Breadcrumb.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const propTypes = {
  /** Additional classes. */
  className: PropTypes.string,
  /** Primary content. */
  children: PropTypes.node,
  /** Custom separator */
  separator: PropTypes.string,
  /** Change the look and feel of the BreadcrumbItem. */
  scheme: PropTypes.oneOf(["red", "purple"]).isRequired
};

const defaultProps = {
  scheme: "red",
  separator: "/"
};

const AbstractBreadcrumb = props => {
  const { className, children, separator, scheme, ...attributes } = props;

  return (
    <ul {...attributes} className={className}>
      {children}
    </ul>
  );
};

AbstractBreadcrumb.propTypes = propTypes;
AbstractBreadcrumb.defaultProps = defaultProps;

const Breadcrumb = styled(AbstractBreadcrumb)`

              display: flex;
              flex-wrap: wrap;
              padding: 18px 26px;
              margin-bottom: 1rem;
              list-style: none;
              background-color: #fbfbfb;
              border-radius: 4px;


              li + li:before {
                content: "${props => props.separator}";
              }

              li + li {
                padding-left: 8px;
            }

              li + li::before {
              display: inline-block;
              padding-right: 0.5rem;
            }

            li a {
               font-size: 14px;
               transition: color .4s linear;
               color: ${props => (props.scheme === "red" ? "red" : "purple")};
               &:hover {
                color: black;
               }
            }
`;

Breadcrumb.propTypes = propTypes;
Breadcrumb.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Breadcrumb;
```

This is the main markup to create the `Breadcrumb`.

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Breadcrumb from './Breadcrumb';
import BreadcrumbItem from './BreadcrumbItem';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Breadcrumb scheme="red">
        <BreadcrumbItem>
          <a href="/">Home</a>
        </BreadcrumbItem>
        <BreadcrumbItem>
          <a href="/">Shop</a>
        </BreadcrumbItem>
        <BreadcrumbItem active>
          <a href="/">Product</a>
        </BreadcrumbItem>
      </Breadcrumb>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What problem I'm facing is I want to use the `active` prop of the `BreadcrumbItem` component inside the parent `Breadcrumb` component to change the look and feel of the item according to the scheme.

I found the first way which is to add the `BreadcrumbItem` styles inside the component itself and use something like this ``` ${props => props.active ? css`` : css``} ```. But Is there a way in `styled-component` to access the child component `prop` inside the Parent component?

Please answer the question in the context of `styled-components`.

Live link: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cdn-u21zm-u21zm)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to move the styling of list item, i.e. `<li>`, to its own component, i.e. `BreadcrumbItem`. In this scenario you won't need to access the state of child component instead you'll be handling `active` state in `<li>` styles. And it'll look more cleaner and separation of concern (which React recommends) will be there.

[**EDIT**]: Sample code to access props of children

```
const List = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {React.Children.map(children, x => {
        console.log(x.props); // get props of children

        return x;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};

const Item = ({ children }) => <li>{children}</li>;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <List>
      <Item>Hello</Item>
      <Item active>HI</Item>
    </List>
  );
}
```

Comment: I also know this but If I want to change the scheme of whole Breadcrumb to something different then What would be the way to style those BreadcrumbItem on `active` prop based on that scheme?

Comment: I've edited the answer. You can give some `active` class when item is active, i.e. `className={['list-item', active ? 'active-item' : ''].join(' ')}`.